# barryvdh laravel/dompdf change my css layout

Tags: css, laravel, pdf, barryvdh

Im using the barryvdh dompdf to generate the pdf file for my view  ,

This is the expected outcome:
[image]

but what I got is ：
[image]

The css design of the view has been change .  im using both css and bootsrap for desgining the page
may I ask how the improve this?

here is my code on view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
            initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=
    "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity=
    "sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=
    "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css"
            integrity=
    "sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz"
             crossorigin="anonymous">
      
        <title>
           Events Ticket
        </title>
    </head>
    <style>
        h6
        {
           color: #96a0a5;
        }
        h3
        {
            color: #b7af92;
        }
        p{
            caret-color: white;
        }
        span{
          color:#b7af92 ;
        }
        
        
    </style>


    <body>
   
        <div class="container mt-5 ms-5 " >
          
            
          
            <div class="row">
         
                
                <div class="col-lg-8 mb-4">
                     @foreach ($tickets as $key=> $ticket)
                    <div class="card" >
                       
                        <div class="card-body"  style="background-color: #48617d;">
    
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="row" >
                                    <div class="col-6" >
                                        <h6 class="card-title">Event : <span>{{ $ticket->GiftGiving->name }}</span></h6>
                                        <h6 class="card-title ">Name: <span>{{ $ticket->name }}</span></h6>
                                        <h6 class="card-title ">Date &Time: <span>{{ $ticket->GiftGiving->start_at }}</span></h6>
                                        <h6 class="card-title ">Venue: <span> {{ $ticket->GiftGiving->venue }}</span></h6>
                                        
                                    </div>
            
                                    <div class="col-6 text-center mt-3" style=" border-left-style: dashed; border-color: #b7af92;">
                                            <h6><span >Ticket No. {{ $ticket->ticket_no }}</span></h6>
                                           
                                            <h6><span class="mt-5">Batch No: {{ $ticket->GiftGiving->batch_no}} </span></h6>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   
                @endforeach
                </div>
  
              
         
            </div>
          
        </div>



        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
         </script>
  
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
                crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
  
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
                crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
code of my controller:

public function GenerateTicket($code)
    {

        $GiftGiving = GiftGiving::where('code', $code)->firstOrFail(); //4.3 ??
        $tickets = GiftGivingBeneficiaries::where('gift_giving_id', $GiftGiving->id)->get();

        # Retrieve the last batch no. from the gift giving.
        $batch_no = $GiftGiving->batch_no;

        GiftGiving::where('code', $code)->firstOrFail()->update([
            'last_downloaded_by' => Auth::id(),
            'batch_no' => $batch_no + 1,
        ]);

     
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('charity.gifts.generate_ticket', compact('tickets'));
        return $pdf->download('event_tickets.pdf');

        

    }
```

Any answer is high appreciated, feel free to drop answer . Thank you in advance.

---

new updated part

this is how it looks like inside the browser

[image]

Comment: Can you create a snippet based on what HTML was generated and add that to your question?

Comment: Did you check your html code by in browser as a simple page ? is you style working fine on browser page or not ?

Comment: @LajosArpad , I Have update a new snippet on what will be generated in the browser

Comment: @AbdulHaseebKhan yes , the style workign fine on the browsing page , I have update my question . You can check on it